# Symfony 3 login is instantly forgotten unless "Remember Me" is used

Tags: php, symfony, session-cookies, symfony-3.4

We've updated a base project from Symfony 2.8 to 3.4. This has largely gone well, blah blah, but I've noticed quite an important issue.

It seems that logging in is instantly forgotten after the request for "check_path" has completed unless the user chooses the "Remember Me" option. -- We do not provide this option for management interfaces to ensure the user has authenticated properly, therefore the management interface can't be accessed at all.

Request flow goes as shown in Symfony profiler:

1. Attempt to access firewalled route.

   - 401 response showing login form with Anonymous token.
2. Submit login form.

   - 302 response with UsernamePassword token. -- This shows the username and password has been accepted.
3. Redirected to original firewalled route.

   - 200 response with Anonymous token. -- UsernamePassword token has gone!
   - *This response does not appear in the web browser's network debugger.*
4. Redirected to login form again.

   - 401 response showing login form with Anonymous token.

Contents of "**app/config/security.yml**":

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\UserBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm:  bcrypt
            cost:       16

    providers:
        local_db:
            entity: { class: AppUserBundle:User }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:                ^/(_(profiler|wdt))/
            security:               false

        assets:
            pattern:                ^/(css|images|js)/
            security:               false

        admin:
            pattern:                ^/admin
            provider:               local_db
            anonymous:              ~
            logout_on_user_change:  true
            form_login:
                csrf_token_generator:   security.csrf.token_manager
                login_path:             user_admin_login
                check_path:             user_admin_login
                default_target_path:    dashboard
                use_forward:            true
                use_referer:            true
            logout:
                path:                   user_admin_logout
                target:                 dashboard
                handler:                auth_listener
                invalidate_session:     true
            switch_user:
                role:                   ROLE_TOP_ADMIN
                parameter:              _login_as_user
            # remember_me:
            #     secret:                 "%secret%"

        front:
            pattern:                ^/
            provider:               local_db
            anonymous:              ~
            logout_on_user_change:  true
            form_login:
                csrf_token_generator:   security.csrf.token_manager
                # login_path should be "user_account_login" or "user_account_auth" depending on which view you want.
                login_path:             user_account_login
                check_path:             user_account_login
                default_target_path:    user_account
                use_forward:            true
                use_referer:            true
            logout:
                path:                   user_account_logout
                target:                 home
                handler:                auth_listener
                invalidate_session:     true
            switch_user:
                role:                   ROLE_ADMIN
                parameter:              _login_as_user
            remember_me:
                secret:                 "%secret%"

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/login$,               roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin,                      roles: [ROLE_CONTRIBUTOR, ROLE_EDITOR, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_TOP_ADMIN] }

        - { path: ^/account/auth$,              roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/account/login$,             roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/account/register$,          roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/account/forgot_password$,   roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/account/change_password$,   roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/account,                    roles: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_CONTRIBUTOR, ROLE_EDITOR, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_TOP_ADMIN] }

        # Change the below "IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" to "ROLE_USER" if this is going to be a private website.
        # This will ensure users have to login on the landing page.
        - { path: ^/,                           roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Routes:

- `user_admin_login` points to "/admin/login"
- `user_admin_logout` points to "/admin/logout"
- `user_account_auth` points to "/account/auth".
- `user_account_login` points to "/account/login".
- `user_account_logout` points to "/account/logout".

I'm wondering if this is cookie related. I did notice that the Symfony session ID cookie ("webapp" below) value is changing after logging in, but it does remain consistent between page navigations elsewhere. It only changes **twice** when submitting the login form. Using the response references above:

1. Attempt to access firewalled route:

   - "webapp" value is "h76n9kcra43stmjb5accnqlg70itnavf" on 401 response.
2. Submit login form:

   - "webapp" value is "15iscbl51k2mjs14bck5m54f4m8qhtme" on 302 response.
3. Redirected to firewalled route:

   - "webapp" value is "ciibpf8h54u2vp3gdi31bvdm5oj3r3ts" on 200 response.
4. Redirected to login form:

   - "webapp" value is "ciibpf8h54u2vp3gdi31bvdm5oj3r3ts" on 401 response.

Contents of "**app/config/config.yml**" session section:

```
session:
    storage_id:         "session.storage.native"
    handler_id:         "session.handler.native_file"
    name:               "webapp"
    cookie_lifetime:    604800
    gc_divisor:         10
    gc_probability:     1
    gc_maxlifetime:     14400
    save_path:          "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions"
```

I tried using different web browsers with very default cookie settings in case something was up with Chrome, no different though.

If it helps, when successfully logged in with the "remember me" option ticked, the token is a `RememberMeToken` -- not a `UsernamePasswordToken`.

Please let me know if any further information is required.

The goal here is to be able to login without needing a "remember me" option enabled.

---

### Edit: User entity model

As requested, here is some detail about the user entity model. It's quite big *(2016 lines)* so I'll just paste in the parts relevant to Symfony's user interface.

**Declaration**

```
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, UserPermissionInterface, DataContentEntityInterface, \Serializable
```

Interfaces `UserPermissionInterface` and `DataContentEntityInterface` are custom for our application. (Irrelevant.)

**Serializable relevant parts**

```
    /**
     * @see \Serializable::serialize()
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize([
            $this->id,
            $this->userName,
            $this->email,
            $this->password,
            // $this->salt,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list(
            $this->id,
            $this->userName,
            $this->email,
            $this->password,
            // $this->salt,
        ) = unserialize($serialized, ["allowed_classes" => false]);
    }
```

**UserInterface relevant parts**

```
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        if (!$this->group) {
            return [];
        }

        $rolesArray = array();

        foreach ($this->getGroup()->getPermissions() as $k => $permission) {
            $role = strtoupper($permission);
            $role = str_replace('.', '_', $role);
            $role = sprintf("ROLE_%s", $role);

            $rolesArray[$k] = $role;
        }

        $rolesArray[] = $this->getGroup()->etRole();

        // If user is top admin, also give admin group
        if ($this->getGroup()->getRole() === "ROLE_TOP_ADMIN") {
            $rolesArray[] = "ROLE_ADMIN";
        }

        return $rolesArray;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Get userName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserName()
    {
        return $this->userName;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
```

**AdvancedUserInterface relevant parts**

```
    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        if (!$this->expires) {
            return true;
        }

        if (new \DateTime() <= $this->expires) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return $this->status === self::STATUS_VERIFIED;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        if (!$this->passwordExpires) {
            return true;
        }

        if (new \DateTime() <= $this->passwordExpires) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->isAccountNonLocked() && !$this->activationCode;
    }
```

**Entity repository `UserRepository` declaration**

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface
```

**Function to load user**

```
    /**
     * UserLoaderInterface
     * @param  string    $userName User to look for
     * @return User|null           User entity, or null if not found
     */
    public function loadUserByUsername($userName)
    {
        $qb = $this
            ->createQueryBuilder("u")
            ->where("u.userName = :userName OR u.email = :userName")
            ->setParameter("userName", $userName)
            ->andWhere("u.status != :statusDeleted")
            ->setParameter("statusDeleted", User::STATUS_DELETED)
            ->andWhere("u.status = :statusVerified")
            ->setParameter("statusVerified", User::STATUS_VERIFIED)
            ->orderBy("u.status", "DESC")
            ->addOrderBy("u.group", "ASC")
            ->addOrderBy("u.created", "ASC")
            ->setMaxResults(1)
        ;

        $query = $qb->getQuery();

        try {
            // The Query::getSingleResult() method throws an exception
            // if there is no record matching the criteria.
            $user = $query->getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException $e) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf("Unable to find an active user identified by \"%s\".", $username), 0, $e);
        } catch (NonUniqueResultException $e) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf("Unable to find a unique active user identified by \"%s\".", $username), 0, $e);
        }

        return $user;
    }
```

This function works fine. A valid user entity is definitely returned.

Comment: Can you show us the User class? I'm interested if it's implementing the serializable interface.

Comment: Which OS ? Try disabling SELinux, it can prevent PHP from writing in session files

Comment: Thanks for the comments both. I've edited with information about the user model. I'm not sure session writing is the issue, the `./var/sessions` folder currently has 481 session files within. (This particular instance is a Debian Stretch VPS.)

Comment: Resolved this with insight from @jedge, posting an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your security.yml, remove:

```
logout_on_user_change:  true
```

or set it to false.

This will solve the instant logout issue, though it will also bypass a security feature of Symfony.

It seems as if something in the serialize() and unserialize() isn't matching, and Symfony then logs the user out as a precaution. With AdvancedUserInterface, Symfony also checks that the AdvancedUserInterface methods match too. If you have anything else going on in those methods which could cause the users to not match (like some bespoke roles management), that could be triggering the logout. To debug, I would suggest returning true in each of the AdvancedUserInterface methods, then re-adding your functionality until the logout gets triggered.

From [Symfony's documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/entity_provider.html#understanding-serialize-and-how-a-user-is-saved-in-the-session):

> If you're curious about the importance of the serialize() method inside
>   the User class or how the User object is serialized or deserialized,
>   then this section is for you. If not, feel free to skip this.
>
> Once the user is logged in, the entire User object is serialized into
>   the session. On the next request, the User object is deserialized.
>   Then, the value of the id property is used to re-query for a fresh
>   User object from the database. Finally, the fresh User object is
>   compared to the deserialized User object to make sure that they
>   represent the same user. For example, if the username on the 2 User
>   objects doesn't match for some reason, then the user will be logged
>   out for security reasons.
>
> Even though this all happens automatically, there are a few important
>   side-effects.
>
> First, the Serializable interface and its serialize() and
>   unserialize() methods have been added to allow the User class to be
>   serialized to the session. This may or may not be needed depending on
>   your setup, but it's probably a good idea. In theory, only the id
>   needs to be serialized, because the refreshUser() method refreshes the
>   user on each request by using the id (as explained above). This gives
>   us a "fresh" User object.
>
> But Symfony also uses the username, salt, and password to verify that
>   the User has not changed between requests (it also calls your
>   AdvancedUserInterface methods if you implement it). Failing to
>   serialize these may cause you to be logged out on each request. If
>   your user implements the EquatableInterface, then instead of these
>   properties being checked, your isEqualTo() method is called, and you
>   can check whatever properties you want. Unless you understand this,
>   you probably won't need to implement this interface or worry about it.

Comment: Ah it could be that my serialize doesn't include the extra properties for advanced user interface (expire, password expire, etc.) I'll try adding them to it a bit later rather than leave this setting off.

Comment: You could override the built-in comparison by implementing [EquatableInterface](https://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/EquatableInterface.html) which would then use isEqualTo() where you can write your own logic, though this could be a step too far. I'd suggest including an $isActive in the serialize too, so the session gets removed if the user account is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this with insight from @jedge.

Turns out the `logout_on_user_change` option being `true` was the cause. Changing this to `false` resolved the issue. -- I'm not sure what this does as there is little documentation on it, and worryingly this has become `true` by default in Symfony 4...

Other things we tried were the temporary removal of CSRF, forwarding, and logout event. -- None of these turned out to conflict. We were also able to login programmatically by manually creating a token for a specific user and dispatching an `InteractiveLoginEvent`, which led us on to the firewall configuration.